# How hide back bar button in navigation controller with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

in the Storyboard (Xcode 6, iOS 8 and swift) i have embedded a TableViewController in a Navigation Controller.

From the object library, i have drag & drop a Bar Button Item as the back button and it show an icon image: when i click that button i show a setting view.

How can i hide that button? In the viewDidLoad() i've tried:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
```

The code is executed (i've tried with the debugger) but the button is always visible.

Answer (score 23):

You have to try this:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: This worked for me using, I am using Version 7.0 beta 3 of Xcode

Answer (score 5):

SWIFT 3

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(nil, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the bar button item is on the right side of the navigation bar you have to set

> self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = []

if the bar button item in question is on the left side do the same, it will remove the bar button items from the navigation item

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
```

Hope this helps.